# Limit of the sum of the funtion and its derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

> Let $f$ be a continous differentiable function on $\mathbb R$. Suppose that 
>   $$L = \lim_{x \to \infty} ( f(x) + f'(x) )$$ 
>   exists. If $ 0 < L < \infty$, then which of the following statments is / are true ?

1. if $\lim_{ x \to \infty} f'(x)$ exists, then it is $0$.
2. if $\lim_{ x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists, then it is L.
3. if $\lim_{ x \to \infty} f'(x)$ exists, then $ \lim _{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ .
4. if $\lim_{ x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists, then $ \lim _{x \to \infty} f'(x) = L$

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you